# DateDiff negative results to 0 in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, datediff, zero

I'm trying to set my results for an expression in SSRS to return 0 if the datediff results is negative. my expression is:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!Check_In_Time.Value, Fields!Date___Time.value)
```

and this one errors and doesn't run:

```
=Max(0,(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!Check_In_Time.Value, Fields!Date___Time.value)))
```

but some results are negative, I want it to return a 0 if it's negative. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This actually worked for me:

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!Check_In_Time.Value, Fields!Date___Time.Value) <= 0, nothing, DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!Check_In_Time.Value, Fields!Date___Time.Value))
```

Comment: this method does work, but @HannoverFist provides a little easier method which will result in a little more readability.  If the Check_In_Time is > Date_time then the result of DateDiff will always be negative

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no function to do this in SSRS.

You'd just need to use an **IIF** to check for it and use **0** if the `Date_Time` was before the `Check_In_Time`.

```
=IIF(Check_In_Time > Date_Time, 0, DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!Check_In_Time.Value, Fields!Date___Time.value))
```